# Email Addresses as Username in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

My Sitecore site requires usernames to be email address.

I can create the users successfully in code but whenever I try to create extranet users manually within the Sitecore CMS on the User Manager it throws a valuation error for email usernames `user name is not valid in the selected domain.`. It appears to be the @ symbol that causes the validation.

How can I update this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above suggests are correct but I found mine included in an sub config located at

```
App_Config/Security/Domains.config

<setting name="AccountNameValidation" value=".+" />
```

Original answer here http://klenke.org/?p=144

Answer (score 6):

You can use this setting:

```
<setting name="AccountNameValidation" value=".+" />
```

Also, consider setting `requiresUniqueEmail` of the membership provider to true so you can't have duplicate email addresses.

More information: http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/sitecore-allow-email-adress-as-user-name/

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the `AccountNameValidation` setting in the web.config

```
<setting name="AccountNameValidation" value=".+" />
```

This will allow all characters in the username